# WiX Post Install Play Audio?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, installation

I have a working MSI bult on WiX 3.9 through Visual Studio 2013.

I would like to play a short, canned .wav audio after an MSI installation completes, so lengthy and /or unattended installs give a clue that they are complete. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get that done? I picked through the bits in the WiX 3.0 Toolset and did not see anything helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WiX [ShellExecute CustomAction](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/shellexec.html) can be used to call an EXE.  The sole purpose of the EXE could be to play a sound without displaying a window and then quit.

See: How To: [Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html)

You could also write a custom action to do the same.  FWIW, "unattended" installs are better known as "silent" installs.  Emphasis on *silent*.

Comment: I am aware of Custom Actions, but there is definitely overhead in working with them. I was hoping there was an "underdocumented" way to play audio from WiX, as there are so many other OS-type hooks. And when the install is on a server, it would be truly silent, but on initial test cycles on attended deployment workstations, simple audio cues can reduce some tedium.

Comment: There is nothing in Windows Installer / Windows Installer XML to play audio files.  You could write a batch file to run your installer and then play a sound when it returns.